# Grape ivy tendrils

Tags: botany

I have a peculiar question. I keep a grape ivy, Cissus alata as a houseplant and I cannot but wonder what exactly makes it decide to grow tendrils? most offshoots have none, only one leaf growing from a node, no matter how many nodes there are and it seems the direction of the growth - vertical, horizontal - is also of no significance. Yet, from time to time, it is like the plant randomly chooses an offshoot that starts to grow quite quickly and grow tendrils. Do you know what processes in the plant cause that?